# Two whiles with multiple conditions doing the same but behaving differently

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a playable chess game for console, for now I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    char type;
    bool alive;
    int coorx;
    int coory;
} Piece;

void print_board(char board[8][8]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("%c", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void convert_coordinates(char x, int y, int *cx, int *cy) {
    /* converts the square to the coordinate, for example a3 -> 05, g7 -> 61 */
    switch (x) {
        case 'a':
            *cx = 0;
            break;
        case 'b':
            *cx = 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            *cx = 2;
            break;
        case 'd':
            *cx = 3;
            break;
        case 'e':
            *cx = 4;
            break;
        case 'f':
            *cx = 5;
            break;
        case 'g':
            *cx = 6;
            break;
        case 'h':
            *cx = 7;
            break;
    }
    *cy = -(y - 8);
}

int main() {
    int y1, y2, csx, csy, dsx, dsy;             /*inputted numbers from user on current and destination squares and coordinates of both*/
    char x1, x2, cp;                            /*inputted chars from user and current piece*/
    bool turn = 1, wcheck = 0, bcheck = 0;
    char square;
    char board[8][8] = {
        {'r','k','b','k','w','b','k','r'},
        {'p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p'},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {'P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'},
        {'R','K','B','K','W','B','K','R'}
    };

    Piece pieces[32] = {
        {'r', 0, 0, 0},{'k', 0, 0, 1},{'b', 0, 0, 2},{'k', 0, 0, 3},{'q', 0, 0, 4},{'b', 0, 0, 5},{'k',0, 0, 6},{'r', 0, 0, 7},
        {'p', 0, 1, 0},{'p', 0, 1, 1},{'p', 0, 1, 2},{'p', 0, 1, 3},{'p', 0, 1, 4},{'p', 0, 1, 5},{'p',0, 1, 6},{'p', 0, 1, 7},
        {'p', 0, 6, 0},{'p', 0, 6, 1},{'p', 0, 6, 2},{'p', 0, 6, 3},{'p', 0, 6, 4},{'p', 0, 6, 5},{'p',0, 6, 6},{'p', 0, 6, 7},
        {'r', 0, 7, 0},{'k', 0, 7, 1},{'b', 0, 7, 2},{'k', 0, 7, 3},{'q', 0, 7, 4},{'b', 0, 7, 5},{'k',0, 7, 6},{'r', 0, 6, 6}
        };

    printf("Type the coordinates of the piece you want to move.\n");
    scanf(" %1c", &x1);
    scanf(" %1d", &y1);
    convert_coordinates(x1, y1, &csx, &csy);

    while ((y1 < 1 || y1 > 8) || !(x1 == 'a' || x1 == 'b' || x1 == 'c' || x1 == 'd' || x1 == 'e' || x1 == 'f' || x1 == 'g' || x1 == 'h') || !(isupper(board[csy][csx]) == turn)) {
        printf("Error, try again.\n");
        scanf(" %1c", &x1);
        scanf(" %1d", &y1);
        convert_coordinates(x1, y1, &csx, &csy);
    }; /* Check if the square is correct */

    printf("Type the coordinates of the square you want to move that piece to.\n");
    scanf(" %1c", &x2);
    scanf(" %1d", &y2);
    convert_coordinates(x2, y2, &dsx, &dsy);

    while ((y2 < 1 || y2 > 8) || !(x2 == 'a' || x2 == 'b' || x2 == 'c' || x1 == 'd' || x2 == 'e' || x2 == 'f' || x2 == 'g' || x2 == 'h') || (isupper(board[dsy][dsx]) == turn)) {
        printf("Error, try again.\n");
        scanf(" %1c", &x2);
        scanf(" %1d", &y2);
        convert_coordinates(x2, y2, &dsx, &dsy);
    }; /* Check if the square is correct */

    printf("%c%d\n", x2, y2);
    if (isupper(board[dsy][dsx]) == turn) {
        printf("%d %d %c", dsx,dsy,board[dsy][dsx]);
    }
    turn = -turn;
    print_board(board);

    return 0;
}
```

On the first while the user is supposed to input a square, the program checks if the inputted square is in the format "a-h""1-8" and if the square contains and upper case char or not depending if it's black or white's turn (as upper case chars represent white's pieces and lower case chars represent black's pieces).

On the second while it's the same but it checks if the destination square contains a piece of the other color (not allowing the capture of your own pieces).

But for some reason the first while works but the second while accepts empty spaces as correct inputs, which it shouldn't. Any idea on what's the problem? Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
I input e4 on the first while and it returns "Error, try again", which is what it should do because e4 is an empty space, but then I input e4 on the second while and it doesn't, but it should because it's an empty space.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the input you use to reproduce the problem, the output you get and the expected output, all formatted as code blocks. You should check the return value of `scanf`. In the successful case it should return the expected number of coverted items, i.e. 1 in your case.

Comment: You know you can replace this monster `!(x1 == 'a' || x1 == 'b' || x1 == 'c' || x1 == 'd' || x1 == 'e' || x1 == 'f' || x1 == 'g' || x1 == 'h')` with this puppy: `(x1 < 'a' || x1 > 'h')` ?

Comment: Aside: `scanf(" %1d", &y2);` is unwise, because any surlpus digits remain in the input buffer. Better to check/restrict the input after the whole value is taken. Unless you specifically want to extract single digits from a sequence of them.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Those are not equivalent. The former is strictly conforming C code. The latter is not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You mean because the range is not guaranteed to be contiguous? Well, in ASCII it is and in EBCDIC `a`~`i` are contiguous too. But formally you are right of course.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the bulky `switch(x)` section above could be similarly simplified too, to `*cx = x - 'a';` subject to Eric's proviso.

Comment: The first while needs a `|| isspace(board[csy][csx])` to disallow moving from an empty space. The second while needs `|| ((isupper(board[dsy][dsx]) == turn) && !isspace(board[dsy][dsx])` to allow moving to an empty space or a space occupied by an opponent piece.

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot cleaner if you did the validation in `convert_coordinates` or a new function `get_move` and wrote `while(get_move() != 0) { ; }` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with these tests:

```
if (isupper(board[dsy][dsx]) == turn)
```

The `isupper` function is not a boolean function returning 0 or 1, it is only specified as returning `0` or non-zero. Comparing the return value to `turn` is meaningless if `turn` is different from `0`.

Assuming `turn` is a boolean, you could fix this issue by writing:

```
if (!!isupper(board[dsy][dsx]) == turn)
```

But `turn` does not seem to be a boolean as its value alternates between `1` and `-1`. You could either make `turn` a true boolean or you might write this:

```
if (!!isupper(board[dsy][dsx]) == (turn == 1))
```

Also note that the second `while` loop test is not an exact transposition of the first one:

```
while ((y2 < 1 || y2 > 8) || !(x2 == 'a' || x2 == 'b' || x2 == 'c' || x1 == 'd' || x2 == 'e' || x2 == 'f' || x2 == 'g' || x2 == 'h') || (isupper(board[dsy][dsx]) == turn))
 //                                                                  ^^^^
```

`x1 == 'd'` should be `x2 == 'd'`

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out the incorrect 'x1' and the *cx = x - 'a'; improvement over the switch.

@Ian but why it doesn't happen on the first while? It returns empty spaces as error like it should, it only happens on the second while. It worked though, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first `while`:

```
    while ((y1 < 1 || y1 > 8) || !(x1 == 'a' || x1 == 'b' || x1 == 'c' || x1 == 'd' || x1 == 'e' || x1 == 'f' || x1 == 'g' || x1 == 'h') || !(isupper(board[csy][csx]) == turn)) {
```

And the second `while`:

```
    while ((y2 < 1 || y2 > 8) || !(x2 == 'a' || x2 == 'b' || x2 == 'c' || x1 == 'd' || x2 == 'e' || x2 == 'f' || x2 == 'g' || x2 == 'h') || (isupper(board[dsy][dsx]) == turn)) {
```

Notice that in the middle of the line you're comparing `x1` to `'d'` instead of `x2` as you did for all the others.